# the return value of WinSock lpfnAcceptEx

Tags: windows, winapi, winsock, winsock2

I want to know when will lpfnAcceptEx return TRUE

This is the description of the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nf-mswsock-acceptex):

> If no error occurs, the AcceptEx function completed successfully and a
> value of TRUE is returned.
>
> If the function fails, AcceptEx returns FALSE. The WSAGetLastError
> function can then be called to return extended error information. If
> WSAGetLastError returns ERROR_IO_PENDING, then the operation was
> successfully initiated and is still in progress. If the error is
> WSAECONNRESET, an incoming connection was indicated, but was
> subsequently terminated by the remote peer prior to accepting the
> call.

But when I debug the program, LpfnAcceptEx always returns FALSE even if a client is connecting to it....

Comment: What completion mechanism have you chosen? It would not surprise me if using IOCP that AcceptEx never returns true.

Answer (score 0):

What does WSAGetLastError() return? If it's IO_PENDING, then you let the async completion occur to handle the client's incoming connection. If it's something else, then a different error occurred.